# NodeJS ExpressJS ETIMEDOUT net.js

Tags: node.js, express, timeout

came in on Monday morning and my node app is not working. No code changes have occurred recently. Users are receiving this error when trying to connect:

```
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:892:19)
```

Seems like something must have changed on the server, although I'm yet to figure out what it is. There was a power outage over the weekend. Any insights as to what would cause this? I receive the same error if I try to connect to my node app on the server itself, so it seems it can't be firewall related.

Answer (score 1):

In case it's helpful to anyone else, the problem was that my backend database services had not restarted after the power outage. Not sure why this was the error thrown, but that's what solved it for me!